# Close slide menu on input focus

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-ui

I have a search bar with and extra options in a slide menu. I have it all working but all i need is the menu to be closed when u focus back on the input again.

https://jsfiddle.net/ny51mzp8/2/

Check fiddle...open the menu and focus back on the input...the menu stays open until u click on the button again. Please i need both options working. I've only heard "keyup" from jquery will accomplish that.

I have it ready this way so far:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
 $('#showmenu').click(function() {
  $('.search-baner').toggle("slide", { direction: "left" }, 500);
  $("span",this).toggleClass("ion-arrow-right-b ion-arrow-left-b");
  $("#showmenu",this).toggleClass("not-pressed pressed");
  });
});
```

Comment: The question is only how to close the menu with focusing on the text input. Simple as that.  Maybe i just wrote too much about it :) (now u can only close it by toggling the button again)

Comment: Forgot to mention there are other buttons in the slide menu...so clicking on the menu wont help as u suggested :( ...it has to be the input that u click on....or just by starting to type.

Answer (score 2):

Use the [`$.focus()`](http://api.jquery.com/focus/) method.

```
$('input').focus(function(){
  $banner = $('.search-baner');
  if ($banner.is(':visible')) {
    $banner.toggle();
  }
});
```

Comment: Thank you!!! Will go with this...it is closing back without the slide effect but lets keep these details for later :)

Comment: Just use .toggle("slide", {direction: "up"}, 1000); and it'll be fine

Comment: Great...i have another function of dimming the screen on focus...thats why the second click...but i managed to put it all together now and the above slide back working nice :) Thanks guys :)

Answer (score 0):

Is clicking on the input ok?

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('#showmenu').click(function() {
    $('.search-baner').toggle("slide", {direction: "up"}, 1000);

    // Only add the listenner once the menu is deployed
    $('input').on('click', function() {
      $('.search-baner').toggle("slide", {direction: "up"}, 1000);

        // Remove the listenner since we dont wan't the menu to open if we click again
        $(this).unbind('click');
    });

  });
});
```

[JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/ny51mzp8/9/#&togetherjs=Ck6GDAH7US)

Comment: It is working...but u have to click twice on the input which would be confusing for the user :)